# Trying to split a string with the | character

Tags: java, android, string, ksoap

Maybe it's because I'm not to android development - but I don't understand the difference between the two ways that I add parameters.

Is String[] not a String?

For example if i run my void onclick below.  The webservice works as intended

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {//Create request
            try {


                //start SoapObject
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                /*List<String> ArgumentPipeValue = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArgumentPipeValue.add("_caseId|apples");
                for (String arg : ArgumentPipeValue) {
                    String[] splitArgs = arg.split("|");
                     request.addProperty(splitArgs[0],splitArgs[1]);;


                    }*/
                request.addProperty("_caseId", "apples");
                //create the envelope
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);
                //Needed to make the internet call
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = getHttpTransportSE();
                //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                //SoapObject soapResponse = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                SoapPrimitive results = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();




            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w("myApp", e.getMessage());
                Log.w("myApp", e.getCause());

            }


        }
    }.start();
}
```

However if I run the webservice the way below I get the error `Unexpected token (position:TEXT Bad Request@1:12 in java.io.InputStreamReader@3709d6f6)`

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {//Create request
            try {


                //start SoapObject
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                List<String> ArgumentPipeValue = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArgumentPipeValue.add("_caseId|apples");
                for (String arg : ArgumentPipeValue) {
                    String[] splitArgs = arg.split("|");
                     request.addProperty(splitArgs[0],splitArgs[1]);


                    }
                //request.addProperty("_caseId", "apples");
                //create the envelope
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);
                //Needed to make the internet call
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = getHttpTransportSE();
                //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                //SoapObject soapResponse = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                SoapPrimitive results = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();




            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w("myApp", e.getMessage());
                Log.w("myApp", e.getCause());

            }


        }
    }.start();
}
```

The only difference is I'm adding the property via `request.addProperty("_caseId", "apples");` instead of `request.addProperty(splitArgs[0],splitArgs[1]);`

What am I missing?  why does this happen?

Comment: An array is not a string, no

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a `String[]` is **not** a `String` (however, calling `String[int]` yields a `String`). But, pipe is a special regex character. You need to escape it in in your split. Like,

```
String[] splitArgs = arg.split("\\|");
```

Comment: Right. It's splitting on empty string or empty string without escaping

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] split = argString.split("\\|");
```

You can then do

```
for(String s : split){
   System.out.println(s);
}
```